# How to Find a class in external reference that implements certain interface?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, interface, reference

I'm working on a project where I have added an external reference. I have searched through this reference with the object explorer. I have found an interface with a function I would like to use. Now to implement an interface you will need a class which have all the functions of the interface.

My question is: is it possible to find a class inside the external reference which may implement this interface already? In other words: is there a good way to see the code behind of an external reference?

I would want to use this possible class instead of making a new one. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with reflection:

```
interface MyInterface { }

public static void Main()
{
    Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("externalAssembly");

    var interfaces = asm.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyInterface)));

    foreach (var i in interfaces)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Found: {0}", i.Name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea this can search an external class.